# Second iteration of XDocument.Save() throwing "Access to Path Denied"

Tags: c#, xml, permissions, linq-to-xml

I'm writing a small class to manage configuration XML for an in-house application.

The following code is called each time a new list of t is loaded, and attempts to serialize data for new t, or, load where t already exists.

I'm missing something fundamental, but I'm not sure where.

The exception is thrown by this code

```
if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "TaskData.xml")))
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();
    XElement rootElement = new XElement("ConfigData",
                                new XElement("Servers"),
                                new XElement("Paths"));
    doc.Add(rootElement);
    doc.Save("TaskData.xml");
}
```

The specific line is 'doc.Save("TaskData.xml")'.

On first iteration, this works fine, and the code creates the template file.

On second iteration, even when the xml file is in the directory, File.Exists returns 'false', and the doc.Save throws the permission exception.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised it's working on the first iteration - because you're not checking a useful file. Instead of calling `Path.Combine` with multiple arguments, you're concatenating `TaskData.xml` with the current directory. You want:

```
if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "TaskData.xml")))
```

It's a pity that your current code even compiles... arguably the overloads for `Path.Combine` should all have at least 2 *required* non-param-array parameters first...

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that...I believe I copy and pasted from a previous version in an attempt to alleviate the issue.

Also, the overload that is being called is actually the Path.Combine(String[]) signature, I'm surprised the compiler takes a single string as an argument, and will implicitly cast that. I could have sworn I've seen instanced of methods that take array parameters refuse that very situation.

Comment: @SurelyTheresABetterWay: It's a `params string[]` - which is fine. If it had just been `string[]` it wouldn't have used it.